# Google Drive Api OAuth2 no token but lots of errors

Tags: java, oauth, google-drive-api

I am trying to access the Drive Api from a JavaFX Desktop app. After I received the initial authentication (aka `code`), I want to get the token to be able to work with the api. The config is set up as a native application in the dev console.

When I attempt to fetch the token I get various http-errors (400, 401, 404, 405, 406, 411). I guess something is wrong with the encoding and/or the way I send the request to the server. 
Here the code:

```
public void sendOAuth2TokenRequest(String initialOAuth2) {
        final String charset = "UTF-8";
        try {
            String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                                   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream();
        output.write(getEncodedUrlParms().getBytes(charset));
        output.close();

        BufferedReader responseReader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), charset));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "OAuth2Request " + inputLine);
        responseReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "OAuth2Request Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private String getEncodedUrlParms() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return "code=" + URLEncoder.encode(getInitialCode(), "UTF-8") +
           "&client_id=" + URLEncoder.encode(DriveHelper.CLIENT_ID, "UTF-8") +
           "&client_secret=" + URLEncoder.encode(DriveHelper.CLIENT_SECRET, "UTF-8") +
           "&redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "UTF-8") +
           "&grant_type=" + URLEncoder.encode("authorization_code", "UTF-8");
}
```

Please let me know what the mean [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#handlingtheresponse):

> The client secret you obtained from the Developers Console (optional for clients registered as Android, iOS or Chrome applications).

Is the `client_secret` needed (mandatory) in native apps?

Comment: Sorry I cant help with java but this might help you track down the problem http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: that looks very decent, I will give it a try. thanks for sharing this info.